# How to access heroku config on heroku server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am updating heroku config through my rails application.
Like-

```
 def add_to_heroku_config
    Rails.logger.debug "Executing: #{ self.name.capitalize }=#{ self.database_string }"
    Bundler.with_clean_env { system("heroku config:set #{ self.name.capitalize }=#{ self.database_string }") } 
 end
```

Now this works from local machine, when i deploy it on heroku, obivously it is not going to work.

Now Is it possible to update/add ENV variables from the application running on heroku itself ?

Comment: I don't know a solution directly, but can you explain what you're trying to do? Maybe I'd know a more platform-independent way to do it?

Comment: I have an interface that saves variable and its value, i want to add those variables into heroku env. I have updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the Figaro gem for this, allowing you to set the environment variables on Heroku, using a .yml file. Figaro contains a rake task doing exactly what you're asking, without making the environment variables "accessible" on the server, obviously for security reasons, by adding the .yml file to .gitignore

See https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro